# How to convert int from an NSimage to JPEG in swift OS Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: swift, operating-system

I extra data from an image and save as int data. I want to convert back to an JPEG image. Thank You.

for j in 1  ..< dataCount!-1  {

```
        var z = ImageArray![j]



        if ( z > 0 ){


           data[j] =z

        }
        else if (z < 0){

            var y =  256 + z

             data[j] = y

        }


        i += 1

    }
```

*** need to convert int to byte ****** but don't know how to do that.

byteArray.writeToFile("/Users/picpath/picture.jpg", atomically: true )

Answer (score 0):

to convert image into bytes you can use the following line of code.

```
 var nsdata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(data[j], 1)
```

The function takes two parameters , first parameter should be an image and the second parameter which is a float is used to define the compression ratio. by default we use "1"

This will convert image into bytes. Hopefully this will help you

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I m not doing IPhone apps . I'm programming Mac OS X . UIImage won't eork

Comment: UIIImageJPEGRepresentation won't work on Mac OS X .  Can you tell me what is equal to that ? Thank you.

Comment: 'let cgImgRef = image.CGImageForProposedRect(nil, context: nil, hints: nil)'

'let bmpImgRef = NSBitmapImageRep(CGImage: cgImgRef!)'

'let pngData = bmpImgRef.representationUsingType(NSBitmapImageFileType.NSPNGFileType, properties: [:])'

// your code bellow


'let imageFile = PFFile(name:"image.png", pngData)'

Comment: Thanks your reply. I really appreciate your effort. I m sorry I didnt tell you everything clearly . I already convert image to int number to store but I don't know revers the entire process. I know how to do that in Java but not swift. If you can help me that will be great. Thank you.

Comment: the last line in the code is used to convert bytes (numbers) into image ...

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I added the last line imageFile. Then Xcode give me this messages " Use of unresolved identifier" . I check the PFFile with google. PFFile is not for OS X. it only for objective C and iOS. I am sorry. Do you have any other idea how to solve my problem.? I also uploaded my program. See answer 2. Thank you.